# How can I split this string up?

Tags: python, sed

I'm trying to split strings up preceding the places where there is a whole, 2 digit number surrounded by whitespace.  Eventually I'd like this to work in Python, but I've been workbenching with sed and I can't figure it out.

My test data looks like this:

```
13 13 13 13 13 9:07.18 9:12.09 9:15.65
14 14 14 2:04.86 2:05.99 2:06.87 14 4:21.51 4:23.51 4:25.00 14 8:56.28 9:01.09 9:04.58
15 15 57.18 57.61 57.95 15 2:02.61 2:03.72 2:04.58 15 4:17.31 4:19.28 4:20.75 15 8:47.15 8:51.87 8:55.30
16 16 56.34 56.76 57.09 16 2:00.69 2:01.78 2:02.63 16 4:13.75 4:15.69 4:17.14 16 8:39.71 8:44.37 8:47.75
17 25.69 25.85 25.99 17 55.62 56.03 56.36 17 1:59.07 2:00.15 2:00.99 17 4:10.76 4:12.69 4:14.11 17 8:33.73 8:38.34 8:41.68
18 25.43 25.59 25.73 18 55.01 55.42 55.74 18 1:57.74 1:58.81 1:59.63 18 4:08.34 4:10.24 4:11.66 18 8:33.73 8:37.04
19 25.20 25.36 25.49 19 54.50 54.91 55.23 19 1:57.74 1:58.56 19 4:08.34 4:09.74 19 8:33.73
```

And I would like it to be split up like this (*note the location of the commas ','*):

```
13, 13, 13, 13, 13 9:07.18 9:12.09 9:15.65
14, 14, 14 2:04.86 2:05.99 2:06.87, 14 4:21.51 4:23.51 4:25.00, 14 8:56.28 9:01.09 9:04.58
15, 15 57.18 57.61 57.95, 15 2:02.61 2:03.72 2:04.58, 15 4:17.31 4:19.28 4:20.75, 15 8:47.15 8:51.87 8:55.30
16, 16 56.34 56.76 57.09, 16 2:00.69 2:01.78 2:02.63, 16 4:13.75 4:15.69 4:17.14, 16 8:39.71 8:44.37 8:47.75
17 25.69 25.85 25.99, 17 55.62 56.03 56.36, 17 1:59.07 2:00.15 2:00.99, 17 4:10.76 4:12.69 4:14.11, 17 8:33.73 8:38.34 8:41.68
18 25.43 25.59 25.73, 18 55.01 55.42 55.74, 18 1:57.74 1:58.81 1:59.63, 18 4:08.34 4:10.24 4:11.66, 18 8:33.73 8:37.04
19 25.20 25.36 25.49, 19 54.50 54.91 55.23, 19 1:57.74 1:58.56, 19 4:08.34 4:09.74, 19 8:33.73
```

The data above, is fairly regular in that the two digit whole numbers are in the range [13,19], but the range I should expect is [10,99].

Could somebody suggest a method to perform the above transformation? I've been at this with regex for a while now but I can't cover all the cases.

Comment: What is the structure of your data? - If you have your data in a `string` then `mydata = mydata.split(' ')`

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal Simply splitting doesn't do what OP wants. Look at the desired output for the first line: there's what looks like a time component that needs to be kept in the same "element" as the preceding integer.

Comment: @not_a_robot Yeah - tricky

Comment: So, `13 13 9:07.18 9:12.09` should be split as `13, 13 9:07.18 9:12.09` and not `13, 13, 9:07.18 9:12.09`?

Comment: Could you `split` the string and reconstruct it in a function based on the contents of the next element? - What is the format of your required output? `List` of `strings`?

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal yes, i guess.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The look-ahead assertion `(?=...)` can solve this:

```
>>> a = """13 13 13 13 13 9:07.18 9:12.09 9:15.65
14 14 14 2:04.86 2:05.99 2:06.87 14 4:21.51 4:23.51 4:25.00 14 8:56.28 9:01.09 9:04.58
15 15 57.18 57.61 57.95 15 2:02.61 2:03.72 2:04.58 15 4:17.31 4:19.28 4:20.75 15 8:47.15 8:51.87 8:55.30
16 16 56.34 56.76 57.09 16 2:00.69 2:01.78 2:02.63 16 4:13.75 4:15.69 4:17.14 16 8:39.71 8:44.37 8:47.75
17 25.69 25.85 25.99 17 55.62 56.03 56.36 17 1:59.07 2:00.15 2:00.99 17 4:10.76 4:12.69 4:14.11 17 8:33.73 8:38.34 8:41.68
18 25.43 25.59 25.73 18 55.01 55.42 55.74 18 1:57.74 1:58.81 1:59.63 18 4:08.34 4:10.24 4:11.66 18 8:33.73 8:37.04
19 25.20 25.36 25.49 19 54.50 54.91 55.23 19 1:57.74 1:58.56 19 4:08.34 4:09.74 19 8:33.73"""

>>> print(re.sub("(\d{2}) (?=\d{2}( |$))","\g<1>, ", a))
13, 13, 13, 13, 13 9:07.18 9:12.09 9:15.65
14, 14, 14 2:04.86 2:05.99 2:06.87, 14 4:21.51 4:23.51 4:25.00, 14 8:56.28 9:01.09 9:04.58
15, 15 57.18 57.61 57.95, 15 2:02.61 2:03.72 2:04.58, 15 4:17.31 4:19.28 4:20.75, 15 8:47.15 8:51.87 8:55.30
16, 16 56.34 56.76 57.09, 16 2:00.69 2:01.78 2:02.63, 16 4:13.75 4:15.69 4:17.14, 16 8:39.71 8:44.37 8:47.75
17 25.69 25.85 25.99, 17 55.62 56.03 56.36, 17 1:59.07 2:00.15 2:00.99, 17 4:10.76 4:12.69 4:14.11, 17 8:33.73 8:38.34 8:41.68
18 25.43 25.59 25.73, 18 55.01 55.42 55.74, 18 1:57.74 1:58.81 1:59.63, 18 4:08.34 4:10.24 4:11.66, 18 8:33.73 8:37.04
19 25.20 25.36 25.49, 19 54.50 54.91 55.23, 19 1:57.74 1:58.56, 19 4:08.34 4:09.74, 19 8:33.73
```

So, the reg exp. you need is`(\d{2}) (?=\d{2}( |$))` which means:

1. `(\d{2})` => Store 2 numbers in group 1 and match an extra space.
2. `(?=\d{2}( |$))` => match 2 numbers and 1 space or EOL, but don't consume them.

The key here is that by not consuming the second matched group, it will be processed again next time that the sub function is applied. Finally, `\g<1>,` will replace 1. with the same numbers and the additional `,`.

Comment: Please explain your regex :)

Comment: @GiantsLoveDeathMetal Please tell me if you need any additional explanation :)

Comment: Glad to see regex has moved ahead in the last 40 years; my regex foo is very `sed` centric, thanks for pointing out this nice addition.

Answer (score 0):

For the fun of sed and because you seem interested in an sed reference for understanding.

```
sed ":a;s/\([^,]\)\(\s[0-9]\{2\}\s\)/\1,\2/;ta"
```

or

```
sed -E ":a;s/([^,])(\s[0-9]{2}\s)/\1,\2/;ta"
```

- start a loop

  - look for

    - something other than `,`, important for looping later
    - a whitespace, two digits and a whitespace
  - replace by the non-comma, a comma and the rest
- loop if that replaced something

Output (exactly as desired output):

```
13, 13, 13, 13, 13 9:07.18 9:12.09 9:15.65
14, 14, 14 2:04.86 2:05.99 2:06.87, 14 4:21.51 4:23.51 4:25.00, 14 8:56.28 9:01.09 9:04.58
15, 15 57.18 57.61 57.95, 15 2:02.61 2:03.72 2:04.58, 15 4:17.31 4:19.28 4:20.75, 15 8:47.15 8:51.87 8:55.30
16, 16 56.34 56.76 57.09, 16 2:00.69 2:01.78 2:02.63, 16 4:13.75 4:15.69 4:17.14, 16 8:39.71 8:44.37 8:47.75
17 25.69 25.85 25.99, 17 55.62 56.03 56.36, 17 1:59.07 2:00.15 2:00.99, 17 4:10.76 4:12.69 4:14.11, 17 8:33.73 8:38.34 8:41.68
18 25.43 25.59 25.73, 18 55.01 55.42 55.74, 18 1:57.74 1:58.81 1:59.63, 18 4:08.34 4:10.24 4:11.66, 18 8:33.73 8:37.04
19 25.20 25.36 25.49, 19 54.50 54.91 55.23, 19 1:57.74 1:58.56, 19 4:08.34 4:09.74, 19 8:33.73
```

Comment: Very nice. Just wondering, could you get rid of some of the backslashes by using extended regex?

Answer (score 0):

Adding to [VMRuiz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43616917/4518341), this outputs a list for each line, instead of one big string. I had to change the regex in order to use `re.split` instead of `re.sub`, and I'm not sure that it's equivalent.

```
for line in a.split('\n'):
    re.split('(?<=\d{2}) (?=\d{2} |$)', line)
```

Edit: This is definitely the same, but a bit awkward:

```
for line in re.sub('(\d{2}) (?=\d{2}( |$))', '\g<1>,', a).split('\n'):
    line.split(',')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non regex Python solution, you can do:

```
s = """\
13 13 13 13 13 9:07.18 9:12.09 9:15.65
14 14 14 2:04.86 2:05.99 2:06.87 14 4:21.51 4:23.51 4:25.00 14 8:56.28 9:01.09 9:04.58
15 15 57.18 57.61 57.95 15 2:02.61 2:03.72 2:04.58 15 4:17.31 4:19.28 4:20.75 15 8:47.15 8:51.87 8:55.30
16 16 56.34 56.76 57.09 16 2:00.69 2:01.78 2:02.63 16 4:13.75 4:15.69 4:17.14 16 8:39.71 8:44.37 8:47.75
17 25.69 25.85 25.99 17 55.62 56.03 56.36 17 1:59.07 2:00.15 2:00.99 17 4:10.76 4:12.69 4:14.11 17 8:33.73 8:38.34 8:41.68
18 25.43 25.59 25.73 18 55.01 55.42 55.74 18 1:57.74 1:58.81 1:59.63 18 4:08.34 4:10.24 4:11.66 18 8:33.73 8:37.04
19 25.20 25.36 25.49 19 54.50 54.91 55.23 19 1:57.74 1:58.56 19 4:08.34 4:09.74 19 8:33.73"""


res=""
for line in s.splitlines():
    buf=line.split()
    for i, e in enumerate(buf[1:], 1):
        buf[i-1]+=", " if e.isdigit() else " "
    res+=''.join(buf)+"\n"  

>>> res
13, 13, 13, 13, 13 9:07.18 9:12.09 9:15.65
14, 14, 14 2:04.86 2:05.99 2:06.87, 14 4:21.51 4:23.51 4:25.00, 14 8:56.28 9:01.09 9:04.58
15, 15 57.18 57.61 57.95, 15 2:02.61 2:03.72 2:04.58, 15 4:17.31 4:19.28 4:20.75, 15 8:47.15 8:51.87 8:55.30
16, 16 56.34 56.76 57.09, 16 2:00.69 2:01.78 2:02.63, 16 4:13.75 4:15.69 4:17.14, 16 8:39.71 8:44.37 8:47.75
17 25.69 25.85 25.99, 17 55.62 56.03 56.36, 17 1:59.07 2:00.15 2:00.99, 17 4:10.76 4:12.69 4:14.11, 17 8:33.73 8:38.34 8:41.68
18 25.43 25.59 25.73, 18 55.01 55.42 55.74, 18 1:57.74 1:58.81 1:59.63, 18 4:08.34 4:10.24 4:11.66, 18 8:33.73 8:37.04
19 25.20 25.36 25.49, 19 54.50 54.91 55.23, 19 1:57.74 1:58.56, 19 4:08.34 4:09.74, 19 8:33.73
```

In `awk` you can do:

```
awk '{n=split($0,a)
      for (i=2;i<=n;i++)
          printf "%s%s", a[i-1], a[i]~/^[[:digit:]]+$/ ?  ", " : " "
      print a[n]
    }' file
13, 13, 13, 13, 13 9:07.18 9:12.09 9:15.65
14, 14, 14 2:04.86 2:05.99 2:06.87, 14 4:21.51 4:23.51 4:25.00, 14 8:56.28 9:01.09 9:04.58
15, 15 57.18 57.61 57.95, 15 2:02.61 2:03.72 2:04.58, 15 4:17.31 4:19.28 4:20.75, 15 8:47.15 8:51.87 8:55.30
16, 16 56.34 56.76 57.09, 16 2:00.69 2:01.78 2:02.63, 16 4:13.75 4:15.69 4:17.14, 16 8:39.71 8:44.37 8:47.75
17 25.69 25.85 25.99, 17 55.62 56.03 56.36, 17 1:59.07 2:00.15 2:00.99, 17 4:10.76 4:12.69 4:14.11, 17 8:33.73 8:38.34 8:41.68
18 25.43 25.59 25.73, 18 55.01 55.42 55.74, 18 1:57.74 1:58.81 1:59.63, 18 4:08.34 4:10.24 4:11.66, 18 8:33.73 8:37.04
19 25.20 25.36 25.49, 19 54.50 54.91 55.23, 19 1:57.74 1:58.56, 19 4:08.34 4:09.74, 19 8:33.73
```